# Trigger PipeWire To Conect Application to Application

Tags: sound, alsa, pipewire, realtime, ardour

When I launch an application (e.g. firefox or chrome) I just want to automatically connect that application to an ardour input and nothing else. Instead whenever I launch firefox, for example, it connects to one of my hardware output devices. I have to manually disconnect that link and connect to ardour - not good.

I assumed there would be a simple way of saying: when this application.name source opens, link to this sink.

I read PipeWire documentation and then WirePlumber but nothing makes immediate sense. When I look at configuration files for PipeWire/WirePlumber I do not know where there are getting different field names from.

**Is there a simple way to set a default PipeWire connection between two applications (in my case browser and ardour)?**

Comment: After one month and trying several things - this still does not work. Sounds from the desktop and applications are automatically connected to the output device by default and I have no idea where this default behavior is coming from or more importantly how to set an application as the default output device and not the sound card.